# warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System"

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dotnet-cli

I am trying to create a client application using WCF.
The server side is a service that is already running.
I was able to get `app.config` and`ServerServiceimpl.cs` from a Microsoft document using the method "Get the service contractor type information using the ServiceModel Metadata Utility (`svcutil.exe`)".

When I run `dotnet-cli`, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\GitLab\xxxxxxxx\yyyyy\ServerServiceImpl\TestApp> dotnet build TestApp.csproj
.NET Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 16.9.0+57a23d249
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.All rights reserved.        

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.202\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.  [C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\GitLab\xxxxxxxx\yyyyy\ServerServiceImpl\TestApp\TestApp.csproj

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.202\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.ServiceModel". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.  [C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\GitLab\xxxxxxxx\yyyyy\ServerServiceImpl\TestApp\TestApp.csproj

C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\GitLab\xxxxxxxx\yyyyy\ServerServiceImpl\TestApp\TestApp.cs(12,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ServerServiceClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\GitLab\xxxxxxxx\yyyyy\ServerServiceImpl\TestApp\TestApp.csproj]

C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\GitLab\xxxxxxxx\yyyyy\ServerServiceImpl\TestApp\TestApp.cs(12,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ServerServiceClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\GitLab\xxxxxxxx\yyyyy\ServerServiceImpl\TestApp\TestApp.csproj]
```

Here are the `TestApp.cs`,`app.config`, `TestApp.csproj` and some of the server-side `ServerServiceimpl.cs`.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ServerServiceimpl
{
    class TestApp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            ServerServiceClient client = new ServerServiceClient();
            try
            {
                // 'client' 変数を使用して、このサービスで操作を呼び出してください。
                client.calendar.get();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException timeout)
            {
                // Handle the timeout exception.
                client.Abort();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException commException)
            {
                // Handle the communication exception.
                client.Abort();
            }

            // 常にクライアントを閉じてください。
            client.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="CustomBinding_IServerService">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/SIService/Impl/ServerServiceImpl.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IServerService"
                contract="IServerService" name="CustomBinding_IServerService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="TestApp.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```
using System.Data;
tem.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="IServerService")]
public interface IServerService
{
    // CODEGEN: パラメーター 'GetAppSchemaRelationResult' には、パラメーター モードを使用して取得できない追加のスキーマ情報が必要です。具体的な属性は 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute' です。
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IServerService/GetAppSchemaRelation", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IServerService/GetAppSchemaRelationResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(TimeZoneInfoTransitionTime))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(DBNull))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(MemberInfo))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(IConsistencyContext))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(TaskCompleteEventSource))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(ReportSaveEventSource))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(WriteButtonEventSource))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(DispatcherObject))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(AbstractInputChkMsgAction))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(DatabaseAction))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(LyLayoutUserGroupRelation))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(AppUserGroupRelation))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(ISISFReq))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(Exception))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(ReferenceTree[]))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(TimeZoneInfoAdjustmentRule[]))]
    GetAppSchemaRelationResponse GetAppSchemaRelation(GetAppSchemaRelationRequest request);

... snip ...

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class ServerServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IServerService>, IServerService
{
    
    public ServerServiceClient()
    {
    }
    
    public ServerServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }
    
    public ServerServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }
    
    public ServerServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }
    
    public ServerServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }
    
... snip ...
```

Thank you for your guidance on where to fix the error.

Comment: I noticed that the version of `Target Framework` in` TestApp.csproj` is inconsistent.
So I changed `<TargetFramework> net5.0 </ TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework> net4.8 </ TargetFramework>`. Then, `warning MSB3245` did not appear. However, `error CS024` is still out.

Comment: I've removed the tags form your question title as per this site's tagging guidelines.

Comment: First check to see if namespace has been renamed. If modified, the full namespace name is required to use the class.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I needed to add the following 3 lines to app.csproj.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include = "ServerServiceimpl.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The build was successful by adding the above 3 lines.
But I don't know what the client can do. In other words, the client doesn't know how to use the many server-side methods. I tried to display `client` for the time being.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ServerServiceimpl
{
    class TestApp
    {
        static void Main (string [] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");

            ServerServiceClient client = new ServerServiceClient ();
            try
            {
                // Use the'client' variable to call an operation on this service.
                Console.WriteLine (client);
            }
            catch (TimeoutException timeout)
            {
                // Handle the timeout exception.
                client.Abort ();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException commException)
            {
                // Handle the communication exception.
                client.Abort ();
            }

            // Always close the client.
            client.Close ();

        }
    }
}
```

Output result:

```
C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\GitLab\xxxxxxxx\kintai\ServerServiceImpl\TestApp\bin\Debug\net4.8> TestApp.exe
Hello World!
ServerServiceClient
```

Comment: There are two main ways to invoke server-side methods.
1.Service operations are invoked through proxy classes, proxy classes are written manually, and proxy classes are generated through metadata.
2.Invoke service operations via channels.